# Node es2015 code not working on production but works on dev-machine

Tags: node.js

I'm using node v4.4.4 on both production and development. I'm using arrow functions. Works on my dev-machine but not on production.

```
/opt/node/backend/server.js:109
    mongoose.model('cv').find({}, (err, cvs) =>{
                                             ^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
        at startup (node.js:129:16)
        at node.js:814:3
```

I run debian 6 on my production and my dev is mac (el captain).

What can be wrong?

**Update**

`node --version` returns v4.4.4 on both production and dev

I can only start node on production with `sudo node server.js`. If I don't have `sudo` I get `segmentation fault`.

I installed v4.4.4 on production with nvm. The version previously was 0.12 I think.

**Update 2**

`sudo node --version` gives `v0.12.2`

I installed v4 by running `nvm install v4.4.4.` I cant run `nvm` as `sudo`

When I open a new terminal `node --version` also gives `v0.12.2`.

Comment: can you prove that you're running 4.4.4 on each environment?

Comment: And also prove it for the actual user that you're running the code as (with `sudo` or something like that).

Comment: Try run `node --use_strict app.js`.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: have you considered using something like Docker to ensure your dev and production environments are truly identical?

Comment: Silly to ask this, but what does `sudo node --version` return, as apposed to just `node --version`.

Comment: @zero298 I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running in prod, the only way to reliably getting the same node version  (installed through NVM) for all users was to run:

```
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

This basically ensures every user using node, will find that version you copied. If you need to update node, then install with nvm and run the command again.

Credit to :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-with-nvm-node-version-manager-on-a-vps